# JS slider only works with compatibility view IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, slider, slideshow

I'm currently building a website and came tot the conclusion my slider doesnt work in IE8. All other browsers are fine, but the slider won't work in compatibility view :(

Anyone that can help?

Much regards.

```
$(function() {

            $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

            setInterval(function() { 
              $('#slideshow > div:first')
                .fadeOut(1000)
                .next()
                .fadeIn(1000)
                .end()
                .appendTo('#slideshow');
            },  6000);

        });
```

Comment: Do you get any errors?

Comment: Where can I see the errors? This is the link, if thes helps www.k2stuc.nl

Comment: Just checked your link in IE8 and IE8 with compatibility mode on, couple of styling issues in compatibility mode, but the slideshow was working as expected

Comment: @QuincyNorbert you can see errors in the console. Hit F12 and choose Console from the available views.

Comment: Tested using IE7 (which compatibility mode is trying to emulate) shows the slideshow working as well. I think the display issue in IE8 compatibility is being caused by the css3-mediaqueries.js script trying to apply rounded corners